# How to load different templates depending upon user input to a the list box

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I'm trying to load a template for displaying a list box.Here i have two different templates

and i have to load one template depending upon the configuration value.First give some idea

that how to load different templates for a single list box.

Here is my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicTemplate.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicTemplate"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>           
     <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Large Template" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Small template" FontSize="10" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>            
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Width="200" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list1}" >
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=size}" Value="Small">
                    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=size}" Value="Large">
                    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LargeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
</Window>
```

Please try to help me i need to do this now. please check the code and reply me soon.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of style triggers in xaml i have used FindResource method like this in my .cs file

Here is my code

```
  string alertTemplateStyle = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlertTemplateStyle"];
        //it will return the value of my configuration file either 1 or 2 depending 
        // upon user requirement

        DataTemplate template = null;

        int size = int.Parse(alertTemplateStyle);

        if (size == 1)
        {
            template = this.FindResource("SmallTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            template = this.FindResource("LargeTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        AlertsListBox.ItemTemplate = template;//AlertsListBox is my xaml listbox name
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your current suggestion?

I guess you could use a DataTemplateSelector to achieve something similar, even though I think DataTemplateSelector usually switches the used DataTemplate based on the items themselves.

//daniel

Comment: Thanks for your reply                                                   Let me clear you one thing that here i don't want to select any template.In the initial stage only i want to display one template either small or large using the configuration value(Here i have taken size).